# Antd: ant-menu-item rendering without class

Tags: reactjs, next.js, menu, antd

I'm using a antd Menu (v4.23.1) and I'm having a strange issue.

One of my ant-menu-items is rendering without the default ant class and gets it after I inspect the element

When the page renders:

[image]

After I inspect the element:

[image]

I´m rendering my Menu items the following way:

```
const items: MenuProps["items"] = NavbarData({ insights, caseStudy }).map(
    ({ name, key, url, component }) => {
      if (url)
        return {
          label: (
            <li className={styles.desktopLinksTitle}>
              <Link href={url}>{t(name)}</Link>
            </li>
          ),
          key: key
        };

      if (key === "logo")
        return {
          label: (
            <Link href="/" passHref>
              <Image className={styles.logo} width={110} height={60} src={logo} alt="logo" />
            </Link>
          ),
          key
        };

      if (key === "login")
        return {
          label: (
            <div className={styles.login}>
              {!account || isTokenExpired ? (
                <Btn
                  text={t(name)}
                  theme="blueBg"
                  className={styles.loginBtn}
                  onClick={handleLoginClick}
                />
              ) : (
                <UserAvatar letters={letters} theme={theme} />
              )}
            </div>
          ),
          key
        };

      return {
        label: t(name),
        key,
        icon: <FiChevronDown />,
        children: [
          {
            label: component,
            key: `Submenu-${key}`
          }
        ]
      };
    }
  );

return (
    <Menu
      mode="horizontal"
      className={cx(styles.menuDesktop, styles[theme])}
      triggerSubMenuAction="click"
      subMenuCloseDelay={0}
      expandIcon={false}
      items={items}
    />
  );
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it?